# Can Azure DevOps Test Plan works with App hosted on AWS and GCP or On-premise environment

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps Service offers number of feature including Test Plans. What are some of the configuration requirements for using Azure DevOps service Test plan for Application hosted outside Azure cloud e.g. AWS, GCP and on-premise hosted app environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Azure Devops Test Plans with any technology you want. It's as old as 2010 even before Azure was broadly used. Especially when you're just using the manual test features, you could even use it to manage the test process of any product, like your fridge, if you wanted to.

There are elements in the Test Hub that integrate with Azure, for example spinning up a test environment after a build and automatically logging the results of automated tests. Most of that can also be used with any other cloud or on-premise environment as long as you use a test technology Azure Devops is familiar with. Vstest is king in this case.

If there are specific features you're looking for, you may need to string it together with with some custom scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot use Azure DevOps Test plan on AWS, GCP.

If you want to use Azure DevOps Test plan, you might have to migrate your CI/CD process to Azure Devops service.

Azure devops supports great integration with AWS. You can use [AWS Toolkit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) to deploy to AWS from Azure devops. [Here](https://medium.com/swlh/connect-azure-devops-to-aws-b89120599103) is a example to connect Azure DevOps to AWS.

You can check [the offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/?view=azure-devops) to learn more about Azure devops test plan.

[Here](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/testmanagement/) is an example of Test Planning and Management with Azure Test Plans.

Comment: But what Test Plan has to do with CI/CD? It is just for functional/manual testing? As per my knowledge there no dependence on Azure Pipeline for TestPlan.

Comment: Azure Pipeline (CI/CD) is platform, language and framework agnostic and one can use it to deploy to any cloud or on-premise using self-hosted agent.

Comment: @Andy Azure devops pipeline can be used for automated test cases. Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops) out. If you didnot have them. Then no need to migrate to Azure devops ci/cd.

Comment: One needs Azure DevOps Service or server to use the pipeline (or Test Plan) because its a feature of Azure DevOps Service which does not exist outside of Azure DevOps.